# Is there a command like \italicmath?

Tags: math-mode, italic

A well-known command is `\boldmath` (equivalent to `\mathversion{bold}`) that makes all mathematics bold. Is there a similar command for italic math, working like `\mathit`, that makes all math (including *numbers*) italic in the current block structure. It is supposed to work like the below M-non-WE.

For me, using `\mathit` is not the solution, since as mentioned, I want something that works for *all* math in the current block. According to [this guide](http://latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf), there is no `\mathversion{italic}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}%it must work with memoir, so no solutions with \it allowed.

\newcommand\italicmath{
   %Do magic for me.
}

\begin{document}

Normal math, with upright numbers: $x = 123$.

{\italicmath Italic math, with italic numbers: $x = 123$.}

{\boldmath\italicmath Italic bold math, with italic bold numbers: $x = 123$.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you ask "How do I locally make my math numbers italic", right?

Comment: Yes, but it is important that it works in the *entire* block structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}%it must work with memoir, so no solutions with \it allowed.

\newcommand\italicmath{\mathversion{italic}}
\newcommand\bitalicmath{\mathversion{bitalic}}

\DeclareMathVersion{italic}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{italic}{OT1}{cmr} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {italic}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}  {italic}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{italic}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathit{italic}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}


\DeclareMathVersion{bitalic}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bitalic}{OT1}{cmr} {bx}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {bitalic}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}  {bitalic}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{bitalic}{OT1}{cmss}{bx}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathit{bitalic}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{it}


\begin{document}

Normal math, with upright numbers: $x = 123$.

{\italicmath Italic math, with italic numbers: $x = 123$.}

{\bitalicmath Italic bold math, with italic bold numbers: $x = 123$.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that?

Comment: @Gaussler only you can answer that.